# Accessing layers in Velodyne Point cloud

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to access layer by layer scans from velodyne HDL 32-E sensor.
If no, Is there any other way round about way to get this functionality ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132811/accessing-layers-in-velodyne-point-cloud/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By "layer" I suppose you mean the points associated with each of the 32 individual lasers.

The velodyne_pointcloud package reports the source of each point as a "ring number", using a sequential numbering of the lasers from 0 (lowest) to 31 (highest). For details, see my answer to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/59743/organizing-point-cloud-from-hdl-32e/).

**EDIT**: The velodyne_pointcloud package provides several nodes and nodelets for transforming raw data packets into a point cloud containing `PointXYZRI` with X, Y, Z, ring number, and intensity.

There is also a [simple class](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/colors.cc) which reads the point cloud and colors the points according to ring number, useful for visualization. Its [message callback](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/colors.cc#L61) shows how to read the data and access the ring number of each point.

**EDIT2**: You can transform the point cloud for a single revolution into an organized 32xN cloud based on ring number, if you want. But, I don't see much advantage to doing that if the device is moving and the points are being transformed into the odom frame of reference.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-02-25**:
Thats exactly what I am looking for, but  i m not able to figure how to convert the sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to pcl::PointXYZIR format.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-02-27**:
Thanks for the edit, I was able to get access to each ring. I was thinking of creating a organized point cloud from velodyne. Accessing ring information will give the vertical relationship but how can i get the horizontal relation b/w the points in each ring ? Or can I have a buffer to accumulate rings and then just stack them ? Please correct me if I am wrong

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-02-28**:
Not sure what buffer you have in mind. You can use normal PCL operations to extract points from a cloud or combine multiple clouds. The 3D Euclidean distance between pairs of points is computed in the usual fashion.

**Comment by [mayuzumi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21479/mayuzumi/) on 2017-02-02**:
Using a vector of pcl::PointCloud pointers should be a good way to accumulate the points of each ring.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-02-04**:
Agreed, @mayuzumi, thanks!